# Join inputs into one string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a custom form-group for an online scheduler. I am trying to find the best approach for joining inputs together into one string for a time. I used jQuery's map function which seems to work pretty good. Am I going to have any issues with this approach on mobile devices or touch screens?

[External JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4u3t2ys2/)

```js
$('input, select').on('change', function() {
  var userTime = $('.form-appointment-time select[name=form-hour], select[name=form-minute], input[name=time_format]:checked')
    .map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get().join();

  var userDate = userTime.replace(',', ':');

  // For preview
  $('.result').replaceWith('<p class="result">' + userDate + '</p>');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group form-appointment-time">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Preferred Time:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <select class="form-control" name="form-hour">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
      </select>
      <select class="form-control" name="form-minute">
        <option value="00">00</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
      </select>
      <input name="time_format" id="time-am" type="radio" value="AM">
      <label for="time-am">AM</label>
      <input name="time_format" id="time-pm" type="radio" value="PM">
      <label for="time-pm">PM</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="result"></p>
```

Comment: You may change `}).get().join();` to `}).get().join(":");` so that you don't need `.replace(',', ':');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine, map, reduce, and join to format your time. You can use reduce to flatten the array, when you get to the point where you need a space.

I added the styling rules for the field as [Виктор Щелкунов](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4949318/%d0%92%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%a9%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2) suggested.

```js
var timeFields = [{
  text: 'Hour',
  value: 11
}, {
  text: 'Minute',
  value: 59
}, {
  text: 'Second',
  value: 59
}, {
  text: 'Millisecond',
  value: 999
}, {
  text: 'Meridiem',
  value: 'PM'
}];

function formatTime(items) {
  return items.map(function(item) {
    return item.value;
  }).reduce(function(res, item, idx, arr) {
    return (idx !== 4 ? res : [res.join(':')]).concat([item]);
  }, [])
  .join(' ');
}

document.body.innerHTML = formatTime(timeFields);
```

## In Action

I modified the `formatTime` function so that you can pass in the index where there should be a space.

```js
$('input, select').on('change', function() {
  var userDate = formatTime($('.form-appointment-time select[name=form-hour], select[name=form-minute], input[name=time_format]:checked').get(), 2);
  
  // For preview
  $('.result').replaceWith('<p class="result">' + userDate + '</p>');
});

function formatTime(items, spaceIndex) {
  return items.map(function(item) {
    return item.value;
  }).reduce(function(res, item, idx, arr) {
    return (idx !== spaceIndex ? res : [res.join(':')]).concat([item]);
  }, [])
  .join(' ');
}
```

```css
select,input{
    width: auto !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group form-appointment-time">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Preferred Time:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <select class="form-control" name="form-hour">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
      </select>
      <select class="form-control" name="form-minute">
        <option value="00">00</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
      </select>
      <input name="time_format" id="time-am" type="radio" value="AM">
      <label for="time-am">AM</label>
      <input name="time_format" id="time-pm" type="radio" value="PM">
      <label for="time-pm">PM</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="result"></p>
```

---

## Another Approach

You can also use an array of stop-points to control when to join values in the array. `Array.prototype.shift()` is a very useful method. It will remove the first item in an array for immediate use. The array will automatically be updated.

```js
Array.multiJoin = function(arr, stops) {
  return arr.reduce(function(res, item, idx) {
      return (
        (stops.length > 1 && idx > stops[1][0]) ||
        (stops.length === 1 && idx === stops[0][0]) ?
          [res.join(stops.shift()[1])] : res
      ).concat([item]);
    }, [])
    .join(stops.length > 0 ? stops[0][1] : '');
}

var timeFields = [
  { text: 'Hour',        value:  11  },
  { text: 'Minute',      value:  59  },
  { text: 'Second',      value:  59  },
  { text: 'Millisecond', value: 999  },
  { text: 'Meridiem',    value: 'PM' }
];

var stops = [
  [0, ':'],
  [2, '.'],
  [3, ' ']
];

function formatTime(items, stops) {
  return Array.multiJoin(
    items.map(function(item) {
      return item.value;
    }), stops);
}

document.body.innerHTML = formatTime(timeFields, stops);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, an a mobile device, the select and input elements have the **display** css property set to "block", and the **width** property set to "100%". Ensure that these elements always "width: auto" and "display:inline-block". See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4m69cmey/) on a mobile device.

```
select,input{
    width: auto !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to store the references to elements for reuse later on as scanning the DOM over and over for the same element is expensive and unnecessary. So, your code could be re-written with as minimal and slightly cleaner code as the following.

```js
//Store the container
var $wrapper = $('.form-appointment-time');
//Store the input elements. This may be useful if at all you wanted to change attributes, such as name etc.
var inputs = [
    "select[name='form-hour']",
    "select[name='form-minute']",
    "input[name='time_format']:checked"
];
//Ensures that only the inputs, selects within the container are considered.
$wrapper.on('change', 'input, select', function() {
    var userTime = $wrapper.find(inputs.join(', '))
    .map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(":");
    var userDate = userTime.replace(/:(?!.*:)/g, " ");
    
    // For preview
    $('.result').replaceWith('<p class="result">' + userDate + '</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-appointment-time">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Preferred Time:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <select class="form-control" name="form-hour">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
      </select>
      <select class="form-control" name="form-minute">
        <option value="00">00</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
      </select>
      <input name="time_format" id="time-am" type="radio" value="AM">
      <label for="time-am">AM</label>
      <input name="time_format" id="time-pm" type="radio" value="PM">
      <label for="time-pm">PM</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="result"></p>
```